# Why selectizeInput does not select the first choices when server = FALSE?

Tags: r, shiny

The documentation of `selectizeInput` describes the argument `selected` as follows.

> selected   The initially selected value (or multiple values if multiple
> = TRUE). If not specified then defaults to the first value for single-select lists and no values for multiple select lists.

I interpreted this sentence as the `selected` argument would be the first element of the `choices` argument if nothing is specified for the `selected`. However, in the following example, after the selection of any numbers for the first `selectizeInput`, the second `selectizeInput` does not select the first choice. It still displays the default message as a placeholder.

Notice that if I set `server = TRUE`, the second `selectizeInput` would be able to display the first choice as the `selected`.

I am wondering why `server = TRUE` or `server = FALSE` affects if the `selected` can be the first element in `choices`. I also want to know how I can make the behavior of `server = FALSE` as the same as when `server = TRUE`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("shinyStore Example"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput(inputId = "Select1", label = "Select A Number",
                     choices = as.character(1:3),
                     options = list(
                       placeholder = 'Please select a number',
                       onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'),
                       create = TRUE
                     ))
    ),
    mainPanel = mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        selectizeInput(inputId = "Select2", 
                       label = "Select A Letter",
                       choices = character(0),
                       options = list(
                         placeholder = 'Please select a number in the sidebar first',
                         onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'),
                         create = TRUE
                       ))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  dat <- data.frame(
    Number = as.character(rep(1:3, each = 3)),
    Letter = letters[1:9]
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$Select1, {
    updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "Select2", 
                         choices = dat$Letter[dat$Number %in% input$Select1],
                         server = FALSE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create the second `selectizeInput` completely on the server side?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("shinyStore Example"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput(inputId = "Select1", label = "Select A Number",
                     choices = as.character(1:3),
                     options = list(
                       placeholder = 'Please select a number',
                       onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'),
                       create = TRUE
                     ))
    ),
    mainPanel = mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        uiOutput('select2')
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  dat <- data.frame(
    Number = as.character(rep(1:3, each = 3)),
    Letter = letters[1:9]
  )
  
  output$select2 <- renderUI({
      req(input$Select1)
      selectizeInput(inputId = "Select2", 
                     label = "Select A Letter",
                     choices = dat$Letter[dat$Number %in% input$Select1])

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer. I have upvoted it. Do you know why the `selectizeInput` needs to be on the server side?

Comment: Nothing specific in this case but in general I have faced lot of issues using `update` functions in `shiny`. Now, I just avoid using `update` functions and use `renderUI` and `uiOutput` almost always. I might be missing something fundamental about update functions but using `renderUI` works for me.